# Python:How to simplify a long boolean expression?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

```
def date():
    date = input()
    d,m,y = date.split('/')
    yd400 = int(y) % 400
    yd4 = int(y) % 4
    yd100 = int(y) % 100
    if m == '2' and d == '30':
        print('Invalid Date')

    elif m == '2' and d == '29' and  (yd400 != 0 or (yd4 != 0 and yd100 == 0)):
        print('Invalid Date')

    elif d == '31' and (m == '2' or m == '4' or m == '6' or m == '9' or m == '11'):
        print('Invalid Date')

    else:
        print('Valid Date')
```

Is there any way to simplify this part?

```
(elif d == '31' and (m == '2' or m == '4' or m == '6' or m == '9' or m == '11'))
```

I'm writing this to verify the validity of a date inserted, without using `import datetime`

Comment: I would also add that you should have simple bounds as  I could input m/d/y and it would pass (12/01/2014) or even nonsense (3245/3483/3859372) and it would pass.

Answer (score 4):

Use a membership test against a set:

```
d == '31' and m in {'2', '4', '6', '9', '11'}
```

Note that your in code may want to handle leading `0` characters on the month and day portions:

```
d, m = d.lstrip('0'), m.lstrip('0')
```

so that `02/03/2015` is still seen as a valid date.

Comment: Ohhh, if if the code is like this? (if y == 5:
                        print(result)
                        elif y = 20:
                        print(ladder,y)
                        
                elif y == 11:
                        print(result)
                        y = 35
                        print(ladder,y)
                        
                elif y == 32:
                        print(result)
                        y = 68
                        print(ladder,y))

Comment: is it possible to simplify it?

Comment: @Lexonss: I have *no idea* what you are trying to do there, comments are not the place for code, really.

Comment: what i mean is if the result to be printed is different, will it be possible to be simplified?

Comment: @Lexonss: not unless you can find a pattern in the expressions that you can exploit.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, your code above appears to be quite happy with a plethora of incorrect input - more than 32 days any month, negative days, or negative months, year 0...

You appear to have looked into getting your leap years right, which is laudable, but a simple

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(input(), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

would not only have "Just Worked", it is also more readable and doesn't require quite as much maintenance as what you produced above.

You asked how to do this without `import datetime` - that's a red flag. Somebody already did the heavy lifting, you might as well benefit from it.